# CORS error when using PHP on IIS on server side and angular 4 on client side

Tags: php, angular, iis, cors

I have 2 web sites that communicate with REST API on my server side.
The main web site has the main domain and the second website has a sub domain.
for example **www.example.com** and **www.admin.example.com**

i have a REST API on the **www.example.com** root directory and when the **www.example.com** address to the API everything is OK, but when **www.admin.example.com** is trying to address to the API, i get an error:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://admin.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I have this PHP code line on my **RestController.php** file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

I also tried to add to my **web.config**  the following code:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

but still i get the the  **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'** header error, or the error "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *, but only one is allowed."

i don't know if it's important, but we are using **Angular 4** for client side.

Does anyone has an idea what is the problem, is it an IIS issue or PHP issue or even client side issue?

Thank You

Comment: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iis-cors-1-0 Microsoft introduced a new OOB module for you to configure CORS responses.

Comment: Thank you!!! that solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously you have to either write your own code or other hacking methods, but now Microsoft ships an official IIS extension, called [IIS CORS Module](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iis-cors-1-0).

You can configure CORS responses easily after installing it.

Answer (score 0):

First you should set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin just in one place. I would recommend to do that in your php controller. Otherwise you might run into that "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *, but only one is allowed."

Second if you are doing a GET request everything is OK but if you are doing a POST request you might run into the "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check..". The reason for that is that your browser sends an OPTIONS preflight request. This request you have to handle on the server side (like you do the post) to be allowed and processed.

You can read more here about preflight requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Further you can find some more information in this thread: [CORS with php headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)